# How to link dll/lib written in c++ by others and call the API in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, lib

I would like to call API written by others in my C# application.

The API is provided through .dll,.lib and .h file and written in C++. Note that I don't have the source code or implementation of dll or lib.

Question 1: 
how to link the dll, lib and .h file which is written in c++ to C# project?

Question 2:
how to call the C++ API in C# after finished linking the dll and lib?

Question 3:
Some of the function in the c++ API is taking pointer argument. How to pass pointer argument in C#?

Below is c++ function prototype that I would like to call in c# application:

```
unsigned long function1 ( unsigned long arg1,
unsigned long addr,
unsigned long *NumberOfBytes,
unsigned long *Data)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2017

Comment: You can reference to this project : https://github.com/prasannavl/WinApi

Comment: This post is overly broad and this general topic has plenty of existing answers on SO. Now with knowledge of new search terms ("pinvoke" and "dllimport") you should be able to find more information and potentially ask more specific questions (don't forget to read [MCVE] guidance on posting code). As starting point for your search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+dllimport+site%3astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called as `Platform Invoke` or `P/Invoke`. P/Invoke is a technology that allows you to access structs, callbacks and functions in unmanaged libraries from your managed code. Most of the P/Invoke API is contained in two namespaces: `System` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices`. Using these two namespaces will allow you access to the attributes that describe how you want to communicate with the native component.

You do not have to do any linking on the c++ for it to be called by C# project. Just make sure the methods you want to be accessed set as `__declspec(dllexport)`. Keep in mind you can not Pinvoke from a static lib, you have to make it dynamic library, dll. On Linux systems .so(shared objects) files. Pointer argumetns are passed by `ref` or `out`

Here are two important articles on the subject:

[MSDN Article:1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop) 
[MSDN Article:2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2017)
[DLL Exporting Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/a90k134d(v=vs.140))

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't link C/C++ dll into C#.
2. You can only call C/C++ via `P/Invoke`

> For example, you have *cpp.dll* which is exporting `int cplusplus_testmethod();`
>   you can call this method by applying `DllImportAttribute`
>
> ```cs
> [DllImport("cpp")] // "cpp" or "cpp.dll"
> public static extern int cplusplus_testmethod();
>
> // Calling cpp.dll!cplusplus_testmethod
> cplusplus_testmethod();
> ```
>
> For more information, read MSDN document about P/Invoke.
>   [Platform Invoke Example (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/platform-invoke-examples)
>   [Platform Invoke Tutorials (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa288468(v=vs.94))

3. You can use `ref`, `out` or `IntPtr`. (You can use `Array` also)

`ref` for **R/W**, `out` for Write only.  For example,

```cpp
int cplusplus_testmethod(int* age) {
    *age = 10;
}
```

This code takes int* for argument and setting it's value to 10. (method does not read it's value, only write) So in this situation, you can use `out`.

```cpp
int cplusplus_testmethod(int* age) {
    if (*age < 0) *age = 0;
    *age = 40;
}
```

This code also takes int* for argument, but it reads value of `age`, and setting it's value to 40. So you can use `ref`. (YOU CANNOT USE `out` for this)

Or you can use `Marshal` class to work with pointers.

[Marshal (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netframework-4.7.2)